# nircmd: I can't run another batch file with nircmd.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have wrote a batch file that i want to run another program with nircmd.exe. But the problem is i can't run it? The batch file(**Matrix.bat**) runs correctlyby double-click it. But when i trying to open it with nircmd.exe, it doesn't run? why?
i tried two method:

**RunMethod1.bat** (for runing another batch file)

```
SET INSTALLPATH=d:\atlantic
start %INSTALLPATH%\nircmd exec show  %INSTALLPATH%\Matrix.bat
```

**RunMethod1.bat** (for runing another batch file)

```
SET INSTALLPATH=d:\atlantic
%INSTALLPATH%\nircmd exec show  %INSTALLPATH%\Matrix.bat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in path of nircmd.exe. I set path of nircmd but i didn't know why it isn't work correctly? with **"pushd"** command i set the path of cmd into where nircmd.exe exist. and **Bow**!!! everything works cerrectly. Maybe a syntax problem. If everyone know that say it here.

```
SET INSTALLPATH=d:\atlantic
pushd %INSTALLPATH%
nircmd exec show Matrix.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

The `exec` command in nircmd does not run batch files but executable files. Change your code to

```dos
start "" "%INSTALLPATH%\nircmd.exe" exec show "%comspec%" "%INSTALLPATH%\Matrix.bat"
```

Now, nircmd executes a `cmd` instance that will handle the batch file execution

Comment: i tried that, but it's not working. Actually i found the problem, the problem was in path of nircmd. why? I don't know